# Element not being removed from list.List

Tags: go, linked-list

If I execute the code below, the element in the list doesn't get removed. I'm pretty sure its because somehow there is a deep copy of the list being created inside Create(). If I change the return of `Create` from `ListWrapper` to `*ListWrapper` the code works.

Still its not intuitive for me why it wouldn't work with the copy. Can anyone shed any light on this? Appreciate the help.

```
type ListWrapper struct {
    Value list.List
}

func Create() ListWrapper {
    var lw ListWrapper
    lw.Value.PushBack(1)
    return lw
}

func main() {
    lw := Create()
    lw.Value.Remove(lw.Value.Back())
}
```

Comment: [list.New](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#New) returns a pointer and all method receivers are pointers. Therefore you cannot expect List to work if you copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C, in Go a slice will be copied to the function/method with a pointer. This means you can change their items but you can't add or delete items from that.

So you have use pointer if you want pass it by reference.

More information: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-a-slice-to-function-in-golang/

Comment: Maybe a basic question but I thought list was a linked list and not a vector so It wouldn’t be internally implemented using slices.